# Global CLI flag in OCaml Core.Command

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I am currently creating a CLI application in OCaml and using `Core.Command`, the CLI parser included in [core (v0.10)](https://github.com/janestreet/core), to parse the command line.

I want to have a global flag that can be used for any subcommand (like the `--paginate` or `--git-dir` flags in git for example).

For instance, I want a `-debug` flag so that the two following commands are valid

```
my-cli -debug hello world
my-cli -debug goodbye world
```

However, I could not find a way to do this with the `Core.Command` API.

Here is a simplified version what I currently have.

```
open Core

let initialize_logger debug =
  Logs.set_reporter (Logs_fmt.reporter ());
  let log_level = if debug then Logs.Debug else Logs.Info in
  Logs.set_level (Some log_level)

let some_func_with_logging () =
  Logs.debug (fun m -> m "the flag debug was passed!")

let hello name =
  some_func_with_logging ();
  Printf.printf "Hello %s!\n" name

let goodbye name =
  some_func_with_logging ();
  Printf.printf "Goodbye %s!\n" name

let hello_command = 
  let open Command.Let_syntax in
  Command.basic
    ~summary:"says hello"
    [%map_open
      let name = anon ("name" %: string)
      and debug = flag "debug" no_arg ~doc:"debug" in
      fun () ->
        initialize_logger debug;
        hello name
    ]

let goodbye_command =
  let open Command.Let_syntax in
  Command.basic
    ~summary:"says goodbye"
    [%map_open
      let name = anon ("name" %: string)
      and debug = flag "debug" no_arg ~doc:"debug" in
      fun () ->
        initialize_logger debug;
        goodbye name
    ]

let main_command =
  Command.group ~summary:"a cool CLI tool"
    [ ("hello", hello_command);
      ("goodbye", goodbye_command);
    ]

let () = Command.run main_command
```

There are two main issues here:

1. the `debug` flag as well as the call to `initialize_logger` is duplicated in every subcommand
2. the `debug` flag needs to be passed **after** the subcommand when invoking the command: `my-cli hello world -debug` instead of `my-cli -debug hello world`

Is there a clean way to handle this with `Core.Command` API?

Comment: I don't know `Core.Command` very well, but how about wrapping your command definitions in something that adds the flag to each command in a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way. It's more of a workaround than a really clean solution, but it might be worth a shot.